# Dot product of the vector r and second order tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Position vector r is given as $\vec r=x_i\hat e_i$ and the second order tensor T is given as: $\overline{\overline{T}}=\frac{\delta_{ij}\hat e_i\hat e_j}{r}+\frac{x_ix_j \hat e_i\hat e_j}{r^3}$.

How to determine (dot product) $\vec r.\overline{\overline{T}}$ by using index notation rules?
I would appreciate any suggestions as I don't know whether I can dot the vector into the two parts of the tensor separately as $\vec r.\overline{\overline{T}}=\vec r.\overline{\overline{T_1}}+\vec r.\overline{\overline{T_2}}$ or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a rank 2 tensor $T$ is thought of as a matrix $M$ (in certain standard basis), $T\cdot v$, for $v$ a (column) vector, is simply $Mv$. However, $v\cdot T$ is $v^tM$ with $t$ denoting transpose.

In your index notation, if $T=T_{ij}e_ie_j$ and $r=x_ke_k$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
r\cdot T &= x_kT_{ij} (e_k\cdot e_i)e_j = x_kT_{ij}\delta_{ik}e_j = x_iT_{ij}\\
T\cdot r &= x_kT_{ij} e_i(e_j\cdot e_k) = x_kT_{ij}\delta_{jk}e_i = T_{ij}x_j
\end{aligned}
$$
Generally, dotting from right or left matters. However, if your rank 2 tensor is *symmetric*, i.e. $T_{ij}=T_{ji}$, then the left and right does not matter. Your tensor $$T=\frac{r^2\delta_{ij}+x_ix_j}{r^3}e_ie_j$$
is symmetric.

For a rank $n$ tensor $T$, the situation is even more complicated. Because now the notion of $T\cdot v$ needs extra clarification. It is a good idea to write $T\cdot_m v$, meaning the dot product is done over the $m$th component. Or better yet, avoid using dot products in this form altogether. Either stick to indexes from start to finish or use the relevant abstract notations related to tensors.

Comment: By doing the dot product, I got $\frac{x_j}{r}(1+\frac{{x_i}^2}{r^2})e_j$. Is this correct or I do need to simplify it more?

Comment: Once you notice that $x_i^2=r^2$ (since there is a summation rule) you're done!

Comment: So I can write as $\frac{2x_je_j}{r}$ or $\frac{2\vec r}{r}$ and if we have $r=\vert {\vec r}\vert$, then we get 2 as the answer?

Comment: Your final answer is indeed $2\vec{r}/r$ (not 2).

Comment: but we have  we have $r=\vert {\vec r}\vert$ as a definition in the question. Shouldn't the final answer be 2?

Comment: It is true that $|\vec{r}|=r$, but there is no way $\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|=1$. In general, the dot product of a (rank 2) tensor and a vector is another vector (not a scalar).

Comment: @Hamed, if we use your prescription, then we obtain, for example, that $e_1\cdot T = T_{ij} (e_1\cdot e_i)e_j = T_{ij}\delta_{i1}e_j = T_{1j}$. How do we interpret this result? What is $T_{1j}$?

Comment: @MichaelLevy You actually get $T_{1j}e_j$ which is a vector, as it should be.